# Adding a dropdown list outside or RenderBody call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a .NET MVC project with Razor views and I would like to implement search functionality that consists of a dropdown list, a text box and a search button.

The problem is that I would like to implement this search snippet in my _Layout.cshtml file **outside** of the `@RenderBody()` call.  This means that the search functionality would be accessible on every page (it would be located at the very top right corner).

I'm trying to find out what is a good way of implementing this.  I can get it to work but it would involve adding same code (do get dropdown values) to all controllers and actions.

```
ViewBag.States = new SelectList(db.States, "Id", "Name");
```

Is there a better way to implement this?  It feels very repetitive to do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a child action method which returns the partial view needed for your header and call this action method in your layout.

Create a view model for the properties needed.

```
public class AllPageVm
{
    public int SelectedItem { set; get; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Items { set; get; }
}
```

Now create an action method in any of your controller. Mark this action method with `ChildActionOnly` decorator.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult HeaderSearch()
    {
        var vm = new AllPageVm()
        {
            Items = db.States
                      .Select(a => new SelectListItem() {Value = a.Id.ToString(),
                                                         Text = a.Name})
                     .ToList()
        };
        return PartialView(vm);
    }
```

Now in the `HeaderSearch.cshtml` partial view, you can render whatever markup you want for your search header. Here is a simple example to render the dropdown. You may update this part to include whatever markup you want (Ex : a form tag which has textbox, dropdown and the button etc)

```
@model AllPageVm
<div>
    <label>Select one state</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.SelectedItem, Model.Items, "Select")
</div>
```

Now in your layout, you can call this child action method

```
<div class="container body-content">
    @Html.Action("HeaderSearch", "Home")
    @RenderBody()
    <hr/>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Make sure you are calling `PartialView` method from the HeaderSearch child action method instead of View method. If you call View method, it will recursively call the same method and you will get a StackOverflow exception

Comment: Great, thank you! +1 for introducing me to couple new concepts I wasn't aware of. I will try this solution as soon as I am back in front of my computer but it makes perfect sense at the first glance.